# Multiple HttpGet that differ by route parameter cannot support different SwaggerResponse's

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` to enhance the generated documentation. I have a simple C# controller that has your standard Get, Post, Delete endpoints. My issues occurred when I added an additional HttpGet with a route parameter, which should be enough to differentiate and still generate the swagger documentation.

Everything seems to be ok until I try to modify the `SwaggerResponse` as one endpoint `/entities` returns a page of entities, where as the `/entities/{id}` endpoint returns a single entity result.

I modified the attribute annotations:

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    [SwaggerOperation(
        Summary = "summary here",
        Description = "description",
        OperationId = "GetPage",
        Tags = new[] { "Entity" })]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, type: typeof(PaginationResult<EntityTransferObject>))]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAsync(
        [FromQuery] [SwaggerParameter("The entity type", Required = true)] string entityType,
        [FromQuery] [SwaggerParameter("The page number to return", Required = true)]
        int page,
        [FromHeader(Name = "Authorization")] [SwaggerIgnore]
        string token)
    {
    
    }
    
    [HttpGet("{id:guid}")]
    [SwaggerOperation(
        Summary = "summary here",
        Description = "description",    
        OperationId = "GetEntity",
        Tags = new[] { "Entity" })]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, type: typeof(ExecuteQueryResult<EntityTransferObject>))]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAsync(
        [FromRoute] [SwaggerParameter("The entity id", Required = true)] Guid id,
        [FromHeader(Name = "Authorization")] [SwaggerIgnore]
        string token)
    {
    }
```

If I then generate the swagger documentation I am met with an error that it failed to load the API definition. If I change the swagger response type to be the same for the 2 /GET methods, it will work. It will also work if I only add the attribute to one endpoint.

If the endpoints are different, they should support different response types for a status code? I've tried using the .NET Core `ProducesResponseType` and that results in the same issue. I have also tried adjusting the return type to be more specific e.g. `Task<ActionResult<PaginationResult<EntityTransferObject>>>` and that has the same issue.

Is there another way to enhance the documentation output for the returned type for the 2 endpoints?

Comment: If you add only one of the attibute,would it work?

Comment: If I remove one of the SwaggerResponses for StatusCode 200, yes it will load the swagger api definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that swagger is getting upset because both endpoints return a type that contains the same transfer object.

e.g.

PaginationResult, which has a list of TransferObjects and the QueryResult that just has 1 TransferObject. Although different types, the TransferObject is resulting in a "can't use schemaId for type Y as it is already used for type Z".

I fixed this by adding the following line to the swagger config

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(
  c =>
  {
    // Removed earlier config for simplicity
    c.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString());
  });
```